# Registro vacío en SQL con PHP

Tags: php, sql

Estoy registrando el nombre de varias imágenes en la Base de Datos, pero lo que no quiero es duplicarla. Entonces necesito saber cómo hacer para saber si está en la base de datos o no.

Este es el código:

```
// Establecer y realizar consulta
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ImpresionesTotales WHERE nombre = '$nombre'";
        //$sql = "INSERT INTO ImpresionesTotales(nombre, carpeta, periodo, total) VALUES ('$nombre', '$ruta', '$periodo', 1)";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)
        or die ("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
        //echo $sql;
            while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                    $totalBD = $fila['total'];

                    // Si la imagen existe en la base de datos
                    if($nombre == $fila['nombre']){
                        // Sumar contador de ImpresionesTotales
                        $sql = "UPDATE ImpresionesTotales SET total=".$totalBD."+1 WHERE nombre = '$nombre '";
                        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) 
                        or die ("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
                        mysql_query($sql);
                        //echo $sql;
                        //echo $fila['nombre'];
                    }//end if
                    else{ ////////////Aquí es donde os digo, que no se como 
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////hacer para decir que la imagen no esta en la BD
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO ImpresionesTotales(nombre, carpeta, periodo, total) VALUES ('$nombre', '$ruta', '$periodo', +1)";
                        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) 
                        or die ("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
                        mysql_query($sql);
                    }
            }//end while

        // Cerrar conexión de base de datos
        mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Yo intenté hacer un else, pero no me funciona.

Comment: Podrías mostrar el error que te salta? O a que te refieres que no funciona, que no inserta/actualiza?

Comment: Hola @rencinas, no me salta ningún error, sino que no me lo inserta. Es más, pongo un echo dentro del else y tampoco me lo hace. Gracias por contestar!!

Comment: Has probado desde el propio SQL a hacer esa consulta? Tal vez te salte error dentro y te pueda ayudar algo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que lo que quieres es saber, anter de insertar, si el registro existe para insertarlo o actualizarlo.

Una forma de hacerlo sería usando la función  [mysqli_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) que nos retorna el número de filas del resultado de la consulta. De este modo si el número de filas es mayor a cero, es que el registro existe, en caso contrario no existe.

Te dejo un ejemplo basado en tu código:

```
 //Consultamos si el registro está en la base de dato    
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ImpresionesTotales WHERE nombre = '$nombre'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)
        or die ("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");


           if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0){
               //Hemos obtenido valores por lo tanta actualizamos
               $sql = "UPDATE ImpresionesTotales SET total=".$totalBD."+1 WHERE nombre = '$nombre '";
               $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)
               or die ("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");


           }else{
                //La consulta no devolvió nada por lo  tanto insertamos el valor
               $sql = "INSERT INTO ImpresionesTotales(nombre, carpeta, periodo, total) VALUES ('$nombre', '$ruta', '$periodo', +1)";
               $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)
               or die ("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
           }

        // Cerrar conexión de base de datos
        mysqli_close($conexion);
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de hacerlo es usando la declaración propia de MySQL **INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY**.

Este comando permite, al momento de insertar un nuevo registro, que si la clave ya existe en la tabla se haga una actualización en vez de la inserción.

Para tu caso, la consulta quedaría de esta forma:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ImpresionesTotales(nombre, carpeta, periodo, total)
            VALUES ('$nombre', '$ruta', '$periodo', 1)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total=total + 1";

    mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or die ("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
    mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Es necesario tener en cuenta que:

- La tabla tiene que tener una clave principal definida
- No hay forma de diferenciar cuando hace un UPDATE o un INSERT

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que es una función y las variables (`$nombre`, `$ruta,` `$periodo`) las estas recibiendo, lo ideal seria ejecutar el `UPDATE` siempre y verificar a través de un

```
if($conexion->affected_rows == 0){
//ejecutar el INSERT
}
```